# Loading Vector Layer using python console in qgis

Tags: qgis, vector, pyqgis, python-2.7

I am using qgis2.6 version and new to pyQGIS. I tried to load a vector file using python console in qgis. I don't know where I am wrong. The layer was not loaded and does not show any error too. Help would be appreciated.The code which i tried is below.

`wb = QgsVectorLayer('C:\Users\new\Desktop\PyQGIS\pyqgis_data\world_borders.shp', 'world_borders', 'ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(wb)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot see the image. What kind of layer are you trying to load? Did you try the recipes given by PyQGIS Cookbook? http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers

Comment: I tried loading a shapefile. I tried the recipes given in 'The PyQGIS Programmer's Guide'.

Comment: did you try to refresh the mapcanvas?

Comment: Yeah i did.Still it doesn't work.

Comment: Add `r` prefix before path string: `r'C:\Users\....'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a Windows OS to test it, but I'm pretty sure the problem is in the path to your ShapeFile. Make sure the path is correct and try with slashes `(/)` or double back slashes `(\\)`.

Answer (score 2):

Add following 
`from qgis.core import *` and try to run again if still doesn't work